# What does "one replica" mean?

Tags: kubernetes

Preliminary remark: The word replica means repetition or copy for me, but:

When someone speaks of "one replica", does that mean one instance or two instances in total? Interestingly, I have come across the use of the former case and this makes me a little insecure. Based on the second case, would one speak of "zero replicas" if there is only one app or instance in total?

Sorry if that question seems a bit vague. Example time. My app or instance has 8 different containers in 8 different pods.

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| #container |    case 1    |    case 2    |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 8 x 1      | "1 replica"  | "0 replicas" |
| 8 x 2      | "2 replicas" | "1 replica"  |
| 8 x 3      | "3 replicas" | "2 replicas" |
| ...        | ...          | ...          |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The question whether the word replica refers to a single container/pod or to the whole app is not important here (it is equivalent), because I will replicate each different container/pod of the 8 containers/pods with the same number. **I would like to know if you would rather use case 1 or case 2** (in discussions among colleagues), or if the numbering is one-based or zero-based. Please mark the question as opinion-based, if necessary.

Comment: good one. Replica is heard across multiple areas, so I prefer "instance" instead. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question depends on many scenario factors. It's hard to say as you did not provide whole scenario. 
However you put `Kubernetes` tag so I can answer regarding `Kubernetes`.

If you are referring to `Replica` in `Kubernetes` it means how many **pods of the same application** should run in cluster.

It's described in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) that, when you create `Deployment`, it creates `ReplicaSet` which is responsible for number of existing pods (number of replicas).

If you will deploy and scale replicas value in `Deployment` it will automatically apply changes to [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/).

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/nginx created
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-7db9fccd9b-4gzfd   1/1     Running   0          9s
nginx-7db9fccd9b-7msm2   1/1     Running   0          9s
nginx-7db9fccd9b-mfj9s   1/1     Running   0          9s

$ kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas=1
deployment.extensions/nginx scaled
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-7db9fccd9b-7msm2   1/1     Running   0          78s
```

In `Kubernetes`, if you will set replica value to 0, you will not have any running pod in this specific `Deployment`.

```
$ kubectl scale deploy nginx --replicas=0
deployment.extensions/nginx scaled
sekreta@cloudshell:~ (composite-rune-239911)$ kubectl get deploy
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx   0/0     0            0           6m48s
```

So if you are asking about meaning of `Replica` regarding `Kubernetes concept`, proper is **case 1**.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, at first I only talked about containers, because in my pods there is only one container at a time (1-to-1 relationship) and the terms container and pods should be used synonymously in this case. Let me count your answer so that my colleague is right and I am wrong with my assessment that using the word "replica" is similar to using the word "copy".